# Calculate percentage of used fields(columns) in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to know if there is any query to calculate the count of used fields(columns) in a table for every row(record).

I want to update my table new field called `percentage usage` by calculating

```
(total number of used columns) / (total number columns) * 100
```

for all records.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks

---

For example:

I have a table named `leads`:

```
Name     Age      Designation    Address

Jack      25      programmer     chennai   
Ram       30      -----------    ----------                   
Rob       35      Analyst        ----------
```

I have added a new column called `usagepercent` and I want to update the new field as

```
Name     Age      Designation    Address     usagepercent

Jack      25      programmer     chennai      100
Ram       30      -----------    ----------    50
Rob       35      Analyst        ----------    75
```

`-------` indicates empty

Comment: Ahm, do you mean to check how many fields are *not* their default value, and there for are 'used'?

Comment: used column means updated or not empty

Comment: @bobby. no, i have 40 fields in my table and about 50k records, wanna calculate updated fields count for every record.i think i am clear!

Comment: @RSGanesh: Wait, you mean you have 50k empty rows in there, and now you want to know which one was changed?

Comment: @bobby: Pls check my example above

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Does empty mean `NULL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work (if the default/empty/unused value of the fields is `Null`):

```
SET @percValue=25;
UPDATE
    leads
SET
    usagePercent =
        IF(Name IS NOT NULL, @percValue, 0) +
        IF(Age IS NOT NULL, @percValue, 0) +
        IF(Designation IS NOT NULL, @percValue, 0) + 
        IF(Address IS NOT NULL, @percValue, 0);
```

You'll have to change percValue according to the number of columns you have.

**Edit:** Adapted solution of RSGanesh:

```
UPDATE
    leads
SET
    usagePercent = (
        IF(Name IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) +
        IF(Age IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) +
        IF(Designation IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) + 
        IF(Address IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)
        ) / 4 * 100;
```

Comment: It does the thing, Thanks bobby

Comment: in other way

UPDATE
    leads
SET
    usagePercent =
        (IF(Name IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) +
        IF(Age IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) +
        IF(Designation IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) + 
        IF(Address IS NOT NULL, 1, 0))/4*100;