# percentage in sql

Tags: sql

How exact percentage calculated in sql ?
For example I wan to calculate the percentage of 155 in 1010
The calculation is (155/1010)*100 right but 
"Select (155/1010)*100" always returns zero.
“Select (155*100)/1010” return the percentage without decimal point.
I need to get exact percentage.

Comment: hey try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682803/calculate-percentage-of-used-fieldscolumns-in-mysql

Answer (score 4):

It's a matter of data types. You have integers and a division with integers result in an integer so `155/1010` is `0` and `0*100` is `0`. In your second example you first calculate `155*100` which is `15500` and then divide by `1010` which will give you `15` still only integers.

If you specify the values as float/decimal you will have that as a result `(155.0/1010.0)*100.0` is `15.34653000` (tested on SQL Server)

[Try here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/123278/)